# Exporting filtered DataTable with serverside Processing (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter-2, datatables

I'm working with DataTables and CodeIgniter, and I've been working on exporting a table after filtering it by each column.

Since we're going to be using a lot of rows of data, I started working on the version where all of the processing (filtering, pagination, search, etc.) was based on the server. I'm currently having trouble exporting my *filtered table* into a PDF.

Issue that arise:

- Only the rows that are currently visible to the user are exported for download. None of the other rows (especially those on other pages--separated through pagination) are included.
- If the number of rows I get after filtering is > the number of rows allowed per page, I don't get all of the rows that I narrowed down my table to.

*I would like some help as to how I would overcome this issue.*

My code is as follows: 
**Views/List.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {



  var oTable =  $('#tablesupport').dataTable({

         "sPaginationType":"bootstrap",
           "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
             "sScrollY": "400px",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sServerMethod": "GET",
                "sAjaxSource": "dthelper",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']],
                "aoColumns": [
                        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
                        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
                        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
                        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },
                        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true },

                        { "bVisible": true, "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": true }
                ]

    });
          //This function works completely fine if the table is processed client-side,
          //I am not as successful on the server-side
        function table2xls(oTable, exportmode, tableElm){
            var xls = '';
            var headers = [];
            var rows = [];
            xls +="<table><thead><tr>";
          //Headers do not appear when server-side processing is used
              $(tableElm+' thead').find('th').each(function() {
                    var $th = $(this);
                    var text = $th.text();
                    var header = '<th>' + text +  '</th>';
            // headers.push(header); // original code
            if(text != "") headers.push(header); 
        });

        xls += headers.join(" ");
        xls += '<tbody><tr>';
        // get table data
        if (exportmode == "full") { // total data
            var total = oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
            for(i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                var row = oTable.fnGetData(i);
                row = strip_tags(row);
                rows.push(row);
            }
        } else { // This branch works fine, however this does not work (in serv. side) for
                 // rows on other pages separated by pagination
             var filteredrows = $("#tablesupport").dataTable()._('tr', {"filter": "applied"});

                for ( var i = 0; i < filteredrows.length; i++ ) {
                    var numCols = 6;
                    var col = '<tr>';
                    for(var j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
                        if(j==2)
                            col+= '<td><div style="font-family: Mv Iyyu Formal;">' + filteredrows[i][j] + '</div></td>';

                        else
                            col += '<td>' + filteredrows[i][j] + '</td>';

                    }
                        //console.log(filteredrows[i][0]);
                        col += '</tr>';
                        rows.push(col);
                };
        /*    $(tableElm+' tbody td:visible').each(function(index) {
                var row = oTable.fnGetData(this);

                row = strip_tags(row);
                row = '<td>' + row + '</td>';
                rows.push(row);
            }); */
        }
        xls += rows.join();
        xls += "</tr></tbody></table>";
        //alert(xls);
        $("#xlsinput").val(xls);

        }




function strip_tags(html) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("div");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}


     $("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
        /* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
        oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
    } );
    $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sSortAsc": "header headerSortDown",
    "sSortDesc": "header headerSortUp",
    "sSortable": "header"
    } );



        $('#tablesupport tr').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });



    $('#export_visible_xls').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        table2xls(oTable, 'visible', 'table#tablesupport');
    });





} );
</script>  





<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12">
<div class="span3">
<div class="btn-group" style="position:relative; right:170px;">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Actions
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 

    <li><a href="#" id="export_visible" value="CSV" />CSV</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="export_visible_pdf" value="PDF">PDF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="export_visible_xls" value="XLS"  >XLS</a></li>

  </ul>
</div> 
</div>



<div id="down-button">
</div>

<div class="span3">
<form action=<?php  echo base_url() . 'exports/toxls/member_export';    ?> method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="xlsinput" name="xlspost"   />
<button type="submit" style="display: none; position: relative; right: 300px;" id="xlsdownload" name="submit" value="Download" class="btn btn-danger" > <i class="icon-download" ></i> Download</button> 
</form>
</div>

<div class="span3">
<form action=<?php echo base_url() . 'exports/topdf'; ?> method="post">

 <input type="hidden" id="pdfinput" name="pdfpost"></input>

<button type="submit" style="display: none; position: relative; right: 500px;" id="pdfdownload" name="submit" value="Download" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="icon-download" ></i> Download</button> 

</form>
</div>
<div class="span3">
<form action=<?php echo base_url() . 'exports/tocsv/member_export'; ?> method="post">

<input type="hidden" id="csvinput" name="csvpost"/>
<button type="submit" style="display: none; position: relative; right: 710px" id="csvdownload" name="submit" value="Download" class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="icon-download" ></i> Download</button> 
</form>
</div></div></div></div>

<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="span2"></div>
<div class="span8">

<div class="table-responsive">
<div id="dvData">
<table class = "table table-hover" id="tablesupport">
<thead>
<tr>

    <th id='nid'>NID</th>
    <th>Name (ENG)</th>
    <th>Name (DV)</th>
    <th>Current address</th>
    <th>Permanent address</th>
    <th>Status</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="fbody" class="rowlink">

</tbody>
<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="text" name="search_nid" placeholder="Search NID" class="search_init" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="search_name" placeholder="Search Name (ENG)" class="search_init" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="search_namedv" id="thaanaInput7" class="thaana" placeholder="ނަން ހޯދާ" class="search_init" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="search_caddress" placeholder="Search curr. address" class="search_init" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="search_paddress" placeholder="Search perm. address" class="search_init" /></th>
            <th><input type="text" name="search_status" placeholder="Search status" class="search_init" /></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div></div><div class="span2"></div></div></div>
```

**Controllers/Record/dthelper()** function

```
public function dthelper(){
    $numCols = 6;
    $this->load->database();
    $aColumns = array('member_NID', 'member_fName', 'member_mName', 'member_lName', 'member_fNameDV', 'member_mNameDV', 'member_lNameDV', 
     'member_currAtoll', 'member_currIsland','member_currAddress', 'member_permAtoll', 'member_permIsland', 'member_permAddress',   'member_status');
    $sTable = "membershiprecord";

      $iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
    $iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
    $iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
    $iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
    $sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
    $sSearch_0 = $this->input->get_post('sSearch_0', true);
    $sSearch_1 = $this->input->get_post('sSearch_1', true);
    $sSearch_2 = $this->input->get_post('sSearch_2', true);
    $sSearch_3 = $this->input->get_post('sSearch_3', true);
    $sSearch_4 = $this->input->get_post('sSearch_4', true);
    $sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);

      // Paging
    if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
    {
        $this->db->limit($this->db->escape_str($iDisplayLength), $this->db->escape_str($iDisplayStart));
    }


     // Ordering
    if(isset($iSortCol_0))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<intval($iSortingCols); $i++)
        {
            $iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
            $bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
            $sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);

            if($bSortable == 'true')
            {
                $this->db->order_by($aColumns[intval($this->db->escape_str($iSortCol))], $this->db->escape_str($sSortDir));
            }
        }
    }

       /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    if(isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($numCols); $i++)
        {
            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                  $this->db->like('member_NID', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_fName', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_mName', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_lName', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_fNameDV', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_mNameDV', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_lNameDV', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_currAtoll', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_currIsland', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_currAddress', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_permAtoll', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_permIsland', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_permAddress', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                  $this->db->or_like('member_status', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));


            }
        }



    }

     if(isset($sSearch_0) && !empty($sSearch_0))
    {

            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_0', true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                $this->db->or_like('member_NID', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_0));


            }




    }

     if(isset($sSearch_1) && !empty($sSearch_1))
    {

            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_1', true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                $this->db->like('member_fName', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_1));
                $this->db->or_like('member_mName', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_1));
                $this->db->or_like('member_lName', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_1));


            }




    }

     if(isset($sSearch_2) && !empty($sSearch_2))
    {

            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_2', true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                $this->db->like('member_fNameDV', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_2));
                $this->db->or_like('member_mNameDV', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_2));
                $this->db->or_like('member_lNameDV', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_2));


            }




    }

     if(isset($sSearch_3) && !empty($sSearch_3))
    {

            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_3', true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                $this->db->like('member_currAtoll', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_3));
                $this->db->or_like('member_currIsland', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_3));
                $this->db->or_like('member_currAddress', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_3));


            }




    }

         if(isset($sSearch_4) && !empty($sSearch_4))
    {

            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_4', true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                $this->db->like('member_permAtoll', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_4));
                $this->db->or_like('member_permIsland', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_4));
                $this->db->or_like('member_permAddress', $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch_4));


            }




    }

     if(isset($sSearch_5) && !empty($sSearch_5))
    {
            $var = 0;
            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_5', true);

            // Individual column filtering
            if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
            {

                switch($sSearch_5){
                    case "Registered member":
                        $var = 1;
                        break;
                    case "Non-registered member":
                        $var = 2;
                        break;
                    case "Ex-member":
                        $var = 3;
                        break;

                }


                $this->db->like('member_status', $this->db->escape_like_str($var));


            }




    }

     // Select Data
    $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false);
    $rResult = $this->db->get($sTable);

    // Data set length after filtering
    $this->db->select('FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');
    $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->get()->row()->found_rows;

    // Total data set length
    $iTotal = $this->db->count_all($sTable);

    // Output
    $output = array(
        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
        'aaData' => array()
    );

    foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
    {
        $row = array();

     /*   foreach($aColumns as $col)
        {

            $row[] = $aRow[$col];
        }*/

        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($aColumns); $i++){
            if($i == 1)
                $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] ." ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+1]] ." ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+2]];
            else if($i == 4)
                $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] ." ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+1]] ." ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+2]];
            else if($i == 7)
                $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] .", ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+1]] .", ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+2]];
            else if($i == 10)
                $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]] .", ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+1]] .", ". $aRow[$aColumns[$i+2]];
            else if($i==2 || $i == 3) continue;
            else if($i ==5 || $i==6) continue;
            else if($i ==8 || $i==9) continue;
            else if($i ==11 || $i==12) continue;
            else if($i==13){
                $status = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];
                $var = '';
                switch($status){
                                case "1":
                                    $var = "Non-registered member";
                                break;
                                case "2":
                                    $var = "Registered member";
                                    break;
                                case "3":
                                    $var = "Ex-member";
                                    break;
                            }

                $row[] = $var;
            }
            else $row[] = $aRow[$aColumns[$i]];

        }

        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

The ugliness of the above code has much to do with the fact that it was written in one sitting.

Comment: You may assume that the export functions (to which there've been references made) work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working.But has bug about searching muti value.

You should my function replace it.

```
//function searching by Jacker & Krucamper myreadyweb.com.
    // Searching by Jacker & Kc.
    if(!empty($sSearch))
    {
        $str_query = '';   
        $search_columns     = array();  
        $total_searching    = count($aColumns); 
        for($i=0; $i<$total_searching; $i++)
        {
            $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);

            if(!empty($bSearchable))
            {
                $search_columns[$i] = array(
                                            'columns'  => $aColumns[$i],
                                            'keyword'  =>  addslashes($sSearch)
                                            );
            }
        } 

        $total_search_column  = count($search_columns);

        if(!empty($search_columns))
        {
            foreach($search_columns as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($key != $total_search_column -1)
                {
                    $str_query .=  $value['columns']." REGEXP '".$value['keyword']."' OR ";
                }
                else
                {
                    $str_query .=  $value['columns']." REGEXP '".$value['keyword']."' ";
                }
            }  
        }
        $str_query =  "( $str_query )";
        $this->db->where( $str_query, NULL, FALSE);        
    }
```

Comment: here is a sample cms that uses datatables with server side processing on codeigniter, for your reference . https://github.com/gencms/sample-gencms/